# Why am I not allowed to add an element through a method of a generic type that extends from a class

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, types

I have a question regarding type generics and lists. I'm still pretty new to type generics so this maybe a stupid question :D

So... I have an abstract class called "Map" which contains an ArrayList of elements which extend from the class "BaseElement" like so:

```java
private final ArrayList<? extends BaseElement> elements;
```

In this class I also have a method called "addElement" to add an element to that list, while also returning the element back:

```java
protected <T extends BaseElement> T addElement(T element) {
    elements.add(element);
    return element;
}
```

I don't know why I can't add this element to the list... The type specified for the "addElement" method is extending BaseElement so the element should also be extending from BaseElement, right?

I also have a "getElement" method which should return an element with it's original type (not BaseElement) from the elements list, which currently looks like so:

```java
public BaseElement getElement(int elementID) {
    return elements.stream()
            .filter(element -> element.getID() == elementID)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Are type generics even the right thing for the job or should I use another technique?

Here is the code mentioned here in it's entirety, which gives a lot more info to this question: https://gist.github.com/Akjo03/8758429c37332688a78a73aa7317569f

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error ? and exception when trying to add ?

Comment: If everything is in a class, maybe you should look into using generics for a class which might help your case: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm. This site contains a section for generic classes

Comment: If you want an "ArrayList of elements which extend from the class "BaseElement", then you want an `ArrayList<Element>`, not `ArrayList<? extends Element>`.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez No it's a syntax error saying that the type is not compatible with each other.

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 Will look at that and see if it helps

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ohhh... that fixed it :D makes sense... thank you!

Comment: @LouisWasserman But how would I go about getting the element back without losing the type?

Comment: Do all the elements have the _same_ type that extends `BaseElement`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman There are three classes (`Node`, `Way` and `Relation`), which extend from `BaseElement` and all of them are going into this list through the `addElement` method. 

Getting them out should be done through the `getElement` method, but they shouldn't lose their type. 

So for example, that I get a `Node` back out from the `getElement` method and not just a `BaseElement`.

Comment: Are all of them in the same `Map`?  Or are there different `Map`s for each of those three classes?

Comment: They are all in the same `Map`. But i fear that this might not be possible, right?

Comment: it seems to me like you need to post a new question and post the link here. this is not peer programming by using comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795035/how-do-i-create-a-list-with-multiple-types-that-have-the-same-superclass-withou