# How do I create a list with multiple types that have the same superclass, without losing the type

Tags: java, list, types

So I have an abstract class `Map` with an `ArrayList` of `BaseElement`'s.

`BaseElement` is also an abstract class, which is extended by three classes: `Node`, `Way` and `Relation`. It only has an attribute called `id`.

Inside the class `Map` i want to have a `addElement` method and a `getElement` method. The `addElement` method should add the element to the list and return the element back, without losing it's type. The `getElement` should find the element inside the list, by it's id and return it (also without losing the type).

Now I tried to use type generics to do this, but I'm still pretty new to type generics.

Currently this is my `Map` class:

```java
public abstract class Map {
    private final String name;
    private final ArrayList<BaseElement> elements;

    protected Map(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.elements = new ArrayList<>();
        this.defineElements();
    }

    protected abstract void defineElements();

    protected <T extends BaseElement> T addElement(T element) {
        elements.add(element);
        return element;
    }

    public BaseElement getElement(int elementID) {
        return elements.stream()
                .filter(element -> element.getID() == elementID)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

For example I want to add an element with `addElement` like so...:

```
public class EarthMap extends Map {
    public EarthMap() {
        super("Earth");
    }

    @Override
    protected void defineElements() {
        Node exampleNode = this.addElement(BaseElementFactory.createNode(new Location(1.2345, 2.3456)));
    }
}
```

and get the element again with `getElement` like so:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EarthMap().getElement(0).getLocation() // getLocation() is defined in class Node, not in BaseElement
    }
}
```

I'm really not sure how to do this, without breaking the logic here. I have to store multiple objects that extend from `BaseElement` in a list, without losing their type.

Can I do this with type generics? Or do I have to use another technique?

Comment: Your basic premise is wrong as objects never "lose" their type. Perhaps you want to use a double-dispatch mechanism, such as the Visitor Design Pattern

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But if I add a Node to a List of BaseElements for example, I don't have access to the methods/fields of Node, which I need in this case. I still need to figure out what types are exactly and how to use them effectively. Will look into the Visitor Design Pattern then and see if it solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: You should consider creating an "abstract Location getLocation()" method  in the BaseElement class and implementing it in your subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

An object does *not* lose its type when retrieved from a Generics-savvy collection (having a parameterized type). You can test for the subtype by using `instanceof` and then cast.

You asked how to call a subclass-specific method on an object retrieved from Generics-enabled collection:

> `new EarthMap().getElement(0).getLocation() // getLocation() is defined in class Node, not in BaseElement`

Using the latest features in Java, this work can be as simple as:

```java
BaseElement element = new EarthMap().getElement(0) ;
switch ( element )
{
    case Node node -> node.getLocation() ;  // Method defined in class `Node`, not `BaseElement`.
    case Way way -> way.someWaySpecificMethod();
    case Relation relation -> relation.someRelationSpecificMethod();
}
```

… with the compiler verifying you have covered all possible cases.

Such an approach can be used instead of the cumbersome [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) mentioned in the Comments on this Question. The pattern-matching and sealed-class features will generally make for more transparent and straightforward code.

## Type is not lost

When you retrieve an object from a container using [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), the object does not “lose its type”. The object’s type is masked, being returned as the more general type parameterized on the collection. But the object still knows its own type.

### Polymorphism as proof

We can verify this fact by way of polymorphism. If the subclasses have their own distinct behavior, we should see that behavior rather than the superclass behavior if their type is preserved.

Let's use a simple example, a superclass of `Animal` with two subclasses, `Dog` & `Cat`.

```java
public abstract class Animal {
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println( "Eating." );
    }
}
```

```java
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println( "Eating meat and veg. Woof." );
    }
}
```

```java
public class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println( "Eating meat. Meow." );
    }
}
```

An app to call `eat` method on each of the animals in a sample collection.

```java
List < Animal > animals =
        List.of(
                new Cat() ,
                new Cat() ,
                new Dog()
        );

animals.stream().forEach( Animal :: eat );
```

When run.

```
Eating meat. Meow.
Eating meat. Meow.
Eating meat and veg. Woof.
```

So, we can see the cats still know they are cats, and the dog still knows it is a dog.

### Methods specific to a subclass

Your Question asks about methods *not* defined on the superclass, methods that are specific to a particular subclass.

For that, let’s add `Dog#snooze` method and a `Cat#petMe` method, each specific to that class only.

```java
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println( "Eating meat and veg. Woof." );
    }

    public void snooze () {
        System.out.println( "I’m gonna take a nap at your feet, if you don’t mind." );
    }
}
```

```java
public class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println( "Eating meat. Meow." );
    }

    public void petMe () {
        System.out.println( "Pet me, now, servant!" );
    }
}
```

To call those specific methods, we need to cast each object from the generic `Animal` to its more specific concrete class.

```java
for ( Animal animal : animals )
{
    if ( animal instanceof Dog )
    {
        Dog dog = ( Dog ) animal;
        dog.snooze();
    }
    if ( animal instanceof Cat )
    {
        Cat cat = ( Cat ) animal;
        cat.petMe();
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Pet me, now, servant!
Pet me, now, servant!
I’m gonna take a nap at your feet, if you don’t mind.
```

#### Pattern Matching for `instanceof`

In Java 16 and later, we can now shorten that code testing `instanceof`. On a single line we can test, cast, and assign to a variable. See [*JEP 394: Pattern Matching for instanceof*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394).

```java
// Java 16+ ➤ JEP 394: Pattern Matching for instanceof
for ( Animal animal : animals )
{
    if ( animal instanceof Dog dog )
    {
        {
            dog.snooze();
        }
    }
    else if ( animal instanceof Cat cat )
    {
        cat.petMe();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println( "Oops, encountered unexpected type of animal." );
    }
}
```

#### Pattern Matching for `switch`

This work gets even simpler using a new feature being previewed in Java 17.

[*JEP 406: Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406) brings that `instanceof` pattern-matching to the `switch` statement.

Beware: You need to set your project & runtime to enable this not-yet-official feature. By default, disabled.

```java
// Preview feature in Java 17 ➤ JEP 406: Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)
for ( Animal animal : animals )
{
    switch ( animal )
    {
        case Dog dog -> dog.snooze();
        case Cat cat -> cat.petMe();
        case null -> System.out.println( "Oops, no animal." );
        default -> System.out.println( "Oops, encountered unexpected type of animal." );
    }
}
```

#### Sealed classes

Java 17, the current [Long-Term Support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version, brings another new feature: *Sealed classes*. In a sealed class, you declare for a particular superclass all possible subclasses. The superclass is then considered closed for extension by any others. Therefore, the compiler can identify, at compile-time, a list of *all* subclasses.

See: [*JEP 409: Sealed Classes*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409)

Notice the `default` at bottom of that `switch` in our code above. It serves as a catch-all in case we have not accounted for all possible sub-types of `Animal`. The compiler can make use of the sealed-class list of known subclasses to tell if our `switch` statement has covered all possible cases.

If we seal our animal, dog, and cat classes:

```java
// Mark the class as `sealed`. 
public abstract sealed class Animal permits Cat, Dog
{
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println( "Eating." );
    }
}
```

```java
// Mark as `final` as one way to seal the superclass.
public final class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println( "Eating meat and veg. Woof." );
    }

    public void snooze () {
        System.out.println( "I’m gonna take a nap at your feet, if you don’t mind." );
    }
}
```

```java
// Mark as `final` as one way to seal the superclass.
public final class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println( "Eating meat. Meow." );
    }

    public void petMe () {
        System.out.println( "Pet me, now, servant!" );
    }
}
```

… then we can further simplify that code above by omitting the `default` case. Furthermore, if we later add another subtype, the compiler will alert us by emitting a compiler error. If we edit our code to omit any of the subclasses (`Dog` case or `Cat` case here), the compiler likewise emits a compiler error.

```java
// Preview feature in Java 17 ➤ JEP 406: Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)
// Combined with Java 17+ feature ➤ JEP 409: Sealed Classes
for ( Animal animal : animals )
{
    switch ( animal )
    {
        case Dog dog -> dog.snooze();
        case Cat cat -> cat.petMe();
        case null -> System.out.println( "Oops, no animal." );
        // NO LONGER NEEDED…  default -> System.out.println( "Oops, encountered unexpected type of animal." );
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

If you want to collect `BaseElement` objects, then retrieve them and treat them as their more specific narrower type (`Node`, `Way` and `Relation`), just cast. Or let the latest Java features do the casting for you.

Comment: Thank you, for this great and extensive explanation! I didn't know they still know their type :) Will implement this, but still on Java 11 so most of these things don't work yet :D Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Suggested changes to your code:

1. `public abstract class Main<BaseElement>`
2. `private final ArrayList<BaseElement> elements;`
3. `protected BaseElement addElement(BaseElement element)`

There is no need to use `extend` as it is already an abstract class

after that, any subclass of BaseELement will work fine :)

Comment: Yes that works, but the thing is, if I take the element out of the `ArrayList` it will be a `BaseElement` and not a `Node` anymore, which I need in this case.

Comment: for some reason the first point did not show up as i write it so it should be 
public abstract class main <BaseElement>

you said that node is subclass of BasElement so any of the following will be fine 

Map x = new what subclass of map you choose;
x.addElement(any baseelement object )  will be fine here

and and getElement will return baseElement which all you to call any method that exist in the baseElement or any class superclass of baseelement but not subclass method of baseelement to do that you need to cast it to it's type so use instanceof and cast it to the right class

Comment: if Class B is subclass of A, and you add B to a list of classes A you can still cast it or ask "instanceof" Class B and it should work.